# SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent() sets button to NOBUTTON in Java7

Tags: java, swing, applet, jscrollpane, swingutilities

As we know `MouseEvent` gets lost in `JScrollPane`, i.e. not delivered to a parent, it is an old bug not fixed yet:
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1362237

So I was using work-around by catching event in `JScrollPane` with a temporary listener and then dispatching event to it is parent to be processed with a real listener.

```
    private class DispatchListener extends MouseAdapter {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed (MouseEvent me) {
        System.out.println("dispatch.mousePressed: " + me.getButton());
        preDispatchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent me) {
        preDispatchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent me) {
        System.out.println("dispatch.mouseDragged");
        preDispatchEvent(me);
    }

    private void preDispatchEvent (MouseEvent me) {
        JScrollPane pane = (JScrollPane)me.getSource();
        MouseEvent newMe = SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(pane.getViewport(), me, tablePanel);
        dispatchEvent(newMe);
    }
}
```

It worked okay, but people with Java 7 started to complain that mouse click has no reaction in the application. After downgrading to Java 6 the issue was resolved, but now I was testing `Applet` and `Chrome` forced me to upgrade plugin to version 7.

After debugging I have figure out that `convertMouseEvent` sets button to `MouseEvent.NOBUTTON` independant of button passed

```
MouseEvent newMe = SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(pane.getViewport(), me, tablePanel);
```

From source code in Eclipse

```
else {
        newEvent = new MouseEvent(newSource,
                                  sourceEvent.getID(),
                                  sourceEvent.getWhen(),
                                  sourceEvent.getModifiers(),
                                  p.x,p.y,
                                  sourceEvent.getXOnScreen(),
                                  sourceEvent.getYOnScreen(),
                                  sourceEvent.getClickCount(),
                                  sourceEvent.isPopupTrigger(),
                                  MouseEvent.NOBUTTON ); //!!!
    }
    return newEvent;
```

**I don't know why is it implemented that way? Is it another bug or feature?**

Seems like I need to create my own object without calling `SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent` and set button from sourceEvent.

Comment: this púossible only for mouse with more than three buttons, isn't it, this issue was solved here, hmmmm you have to search for downvoted post by @camickr :-)

Comment: @mKorbel, `Point p = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(pane.getViewport(), me.getPoint(), tablePanel);
   MouseEvent newMe = new MouseEvent(tablePanel, me.getID(), me.getWhen(), me.getModifiers(), p.x,p.y, me.getXOnScreen(), me.getYOnScreen(), me.getClickCount(), me.isPopupTrigger(), me.getButton());` solves the problem but question remains

Comment: _why?_ Shit happens ... ;-) You might consider filing an issue in the snoracle's bug parade

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting issue. The use of `MouseEvent.NOBUTTON` in `SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent` sure looks very strange. However, I'm unable to reproduce the problem with Java 7; for me the `button` field of the converted mouse event is correct for Java 7 and 6 (using 1.7.0-b147 64-bit and 1.6.0_21-b07 64-bit on a Windows 7 laptop).

Debugging through the `MouseEvent` constructor I saw that while the `button` field is initially set to zero, the call to `setNewModifiers` at the end of the constructor changes `button` based on the `modifiers` field (which receives its value from `sourceEvent.getModifiers` when the converted mouse event is constructed in `SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent`).

The converted mouse events from a single click look like this (for Java 7):

```
java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_PRESSED,(185,175),absolute(593,305),button=1,modifiers=Button1,extModifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,381x259,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_RELEASED,(185,175),absolute(593,305),button=1,modifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,381x259,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
```

**In response to your questions**: I think `MouseEvent.NOBUTTON` is passed to the `MouseEvent` constructor because the value of the `button` field will be determined by the value of the `modifiers` field anyway. On my laptop, things work as I expected for both Java 7 and 6, so it doesn't look like a bug to me. Is your application running in a browser and does that make a difference in how the mouse events are converted? Did you create a work around to solve the issue already or else could you share some of the applet code?

*Other event types*
The first two cases that are handled by `SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent` create a `MouseWheelEvent` or a `MenuDragMouseEvent` object. Both constructors (eventually) call a `MouseEvent` constructor with a `MouseEvent.NOBUTTON` parameter. (Looking at these events (without conversion) on my laptop, the `button` field of a `MouseWheelEvent` is always zero (my mouse has only one wheel). For `MenuDragMouseEvent` objects `button` is equal to one for the `menuDragMouseReleased` event and is zero otherwise, while the `modifiers` field is always equal to `BUTTON1_MASK`.) So it looks like `MouseEvent.NOBUTTON` is quite popular as a parameter to the `MouseEvent` constructors.

Answer (score 0):

See https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7181403 - it looks like convertMouseEvent() did not change recently, so other code changes must be responsible for the change you see in Java 7 (I can reproduce the issue here as well with 1.7.0_21).

In any case, it looks like the problem has been solved in Java 8.